# npm run Build:dev error when doing Advance UI Customization

Tags: node.js, npm, wso2, npm-run

I wanted to customize the UI elements in the publisher portal and followed [this guide](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/customize-product/customizations/advanced-ui-customization/)

But I get the following error when running this in cmd;
`npm run build:dev`

> ```
> ERROR in ./node_modules/@material-ui/core/esm/styles/createPalette.js Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js): SyntaxError: .\Downloads\wso2am-4.1.0\repository\deployment\server\jaggeryapps\publisher\node_modules@material-ui\core\esm\styles\createPalette.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (174:319)
> ```

I’m using node version `16.14.0` and npm version `8.9.0`.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try with the node version 12.x or 14.x? It works with those versions.